# Maximum dimension of a simultaneous anisotropic subspace of quadratic forms over $ \mathbb{Q} $

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, quadratic-forms, rational-points

Let $(V,q )$ be a  quadratic space over $ \mathbb{Q} $. A subspace  $ U $ is called  totally isotropic if  $ q(x) = 0 $ for all $ x \in U $  and a subspace $ U $ is called an anisotropic subspace if $ q(x) \neq 0 $ for all non zero $ x \in U $. Let us consider two quadratic forms $ q_{1}$, $q_{2} $, defined by
$$ q_{1}(a,b,c,d) = ab + 2 ac - 2 ad - 2 bc + 2 bd  - cd  $$ and $$ q_{2}(a,b,c,d) = 2 a^{2} - 13 ab + 4 ac + 4 ad + 2 b^{2} + 4 bc + 4 bd + 2 c^{2} - 13 cd + 2 d^{2} .$$
Then, what is the maximum dimension of a common anisotropic subspace of $ q_{1} $ and  $ q_{2} $?

Comment: Context would help: how did these particular ones arise, or are you hoping for a general algorithm? Do you have info on the local behavior? (Thinking of Hasse-Minkowski...)

Comment: I have tried , I computed some anisotropic  subspace of 1st one but some vector is isotropic  for 2nd one.

Comment: Is there any algorithm?

Comment: Where do these particular forms come from?

Comment: These forms come from  lot of calculations   , that don't help much. Does there  any trick  to guess  the anisotropic  subspace   we can also think what is the maximum  dimension  of totally isotropic  subspace.

Comment: The two quadratic forms are isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Does it help ?

Comment: how there is an isomorphism ? what does isomorphism meant here?

Comment: @SugataMandal Two quadratic spaces are isomorphic if there is an isomorphism between the underlying vector spaces preserving the quadratic/bilinear form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimension 4 is clearly impossible since your quadratic forms are isotropic, but dimension 3 is possible.

The following SageMath code generate random 3-dimensional subspaces and check whether they are simultaneously isotropic for both forms. It finds quite a lot of such subspaces, as an example you can take the subspace generated by the vectors

$$\pmatrix{2\cr0\cr0\cr1}, \pmatrix{-1\cr0\cr1\cr1}, \pmatrix{1\cr1\cr12\cr0}$$

```
M1 = Matrix([[ 0, 1, 2,-2],
             [ 1, 0,-2, 2],
             [ 2,-2, 0,-1],
             [-2, 2,-1, 0]])
M2 = Matrix([[  4,-13,  4,  4],
             [-13,  4,  4,  4],
             [  4,  4,  4,-13],
             [  4,  4,-13,  4]])
Q1 = QuadraticForm(QQ, M1)
Q2 = QuadraticForm(QQ, M2)

for k in range(50):

    basis = random_matrix(ZZ, 3, 4)

    N1 = matrix(QQ, 3, 3, lambda i, j: Q1.bilinear_map(basis[i], basis[j]))
    N2 = matrix(QQ, 3, 3, lambda i, j: Q2.bilinear_map(basis[i], basis[j]))

    q1 = QuadraticForm(QQ, N1)
    q2 = QuadraticForm(QQ, N2)
    
    if q1.anisotropic_primes() and q2.anisotropic_primes():
        print(basis)
        print()
```

Comment: What does mean anisotropic primes here? So in general for any quadratic  form we can compute an anisotropic  subspace  of a quadratic  form or common anisotropic subspace for both with the help of sage math?

Comment: q.anisotropic_primes() gives the list of all primes $p$ (including $\infty$) such that $q$ is anisotropic over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. So by Hasse-Minkowski q is anisotropic over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if q.anisotropic_primes() is nonempty (note that in python for a list L, "if L" evaluates to False if L is empty and True otherwise).

Comment: Thanks @Antoine Labelle , now I understand